# Block Heights at which important changes happened to the protocol

Tags: rpc, protocol

I've been exploring the json dumps of each block through `./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/<bid>` and wanted to know the block heights at which some important changes might have happened to the protocol in its current history that would have modified/added new json fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the height of the first and the last block of each protocol in some block explorers (e.g. https://tezos.id/protocols).

You can also consult the documentation's Protocols section (starting from [003](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html)), which should capture these changes.